# How to Calculate the flux of the Vector Field on the surface $z = 1-x^2-y^2$ ( getting normal vector $(0,0,0)$ at the point $(0,0,1)$ ?!!! )

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, surface-integrals

> Let $S$ be the surface $z = 1-x^2-y^2 , 0\leq z$.
>
> Find $\int_{S} x^2z~dydz + y^2z~dzdx + (x^2+y^2)~dxdy$.
> Choose the direction of the normal upwards.

so i calculated the flux and i got that it is $\boxed{\frac{\pi}{2}}$. i am not sure if that is right

Parametrization $R(\theta,r) = (r\cos(\theta),r\sin(\theta),1-r^2)$

and the normal is $(2r^2\cos(\theta),2r^2\sin(\theta),r)$ i feel like its not right but i calculated it many times at the point $(0,0,1) ~ r =  0$ but the normal is $(0,0,0)$

$\int_{S}\vec{F} _\dot{} \vec{n}$ = $\int_{\theta = 0}^{\theta = 2\pi}\int_{r=0}^{r=1}~~(2r^4-2r^6)(\sin^3{\theta}+\cos^3{\theta}) + r^3~~drd\theta$

Comment: anyone ? i need help , i feel like the normal is Wrong at the point (0,0,1) i get the normal vector (0,0,0)

Comment: Your calculations and the result are correct. The magnitude of the normal vector is zero when $r = 0$, but the $x$ and $y$ components are infinitesimals of higher order for small $r$, so the vector is approximately vertical and pointing upwards, and the unit normal is close to $(0, 0, 1)$.

Comment: But without parametrizing the normal is $(0,0,1)$ and with it is (0,0,0) why ?

Comment: The *unit* normal is close to $(0, 0, 1)$. The unit normal is $(2 r \cos \theta, 2 r \sin \theta, 1)/\sqrt{1 + 4 r^2}$.